# Django not detecting new tables, migrations

Tags: python, django, migration, syncdb

I've created two models:

```
class A1(models.Model):
    #insert code

class A2(models.Model)
    #insert code
```

However, when I run python3 manage.py migrate it says "No migrations to apply."

When I check my /admin I can only see Groups, Users under "Authentication and Authorization" but I can't see my tables at all. Anyone have any idea?

Solution: Had the wrong app name in "INSTALLED_APPS". Added the correct one and it worked.

Comment: first do python3 manage.py makemigrations them python3 manage.py migrate

Comment: @GeoJacob It says "No changes detected".